# How to edit icon of SearchBar Xamarin Forms on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, icons, edit, searchbar

I need your help !

I work on a mobile development project, cross-platform. I use Visual Studio with Xamarin Forms.
I want to make a page with a SearchBar (Xamarin.Forms class), but, my problem is the personalisation of the SearchBar icon, especially on the Platform Android. My search led me to nothing.
I would be very grateful if you know of a way to edit icon. (I have a model to follow, so It’s well the icon that I want to change and not the color).

Thank you in advance !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU6QL.png)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[Introduction to Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/)

You can subclass the stock `Xamarin.Forms` controls fairly easily for making minor platform-oriented changes to the controls.

In the examples above, I create two SearchBar subclasses, one to allow a custom icon and the other to remove the icon, the `Xamarin.Android` renders look like:

[image]

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged (e);
    if (Control != null) {
        var searchView = Control;
        searchView.Iconified = true;
        searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault (false);
        // (Resource.Id.search_mag_icon); is wrong / Xammie bug
        int searchIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier ("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
        var icon = searchView.FindViewById (searchIconId);
        (icon as ImageView).SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.icon);
    }
```

---

[image]

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged (e);
    if (Control != null) {
        var searchView = Control;
        searchView.Iconified = true;
        searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault (false);
        // (Resource.Id.search_mag_icon); is wrong / Xammie bug
        int searchIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier ("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
        var icon = searchView.FindViewById (searchIconId);
        icon.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sushil, I have follow your code it's work's great but when I start type text in search bar it will again show the search image. Now just hide the search image at first time. I want to hide search image permanently. How can I achieve that.

Comment: @Deepak In the renderer you can set the icon visibility,  `icon.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;` Set it when the control contains text (use an event or listener within the renderer

Comment: Thanks Sushil, I am using onelementproperychanged method for hiding search image while user type text in search bar but at first time search image is visible when user start type text it will gone. I want hide search image in first time also.

Comment: @Deepak I'm not sure I understand, do you want the icon to hide when the search entry obtains focus but before the user entries the first character?

Comment: yes sushil, Actually at first time I am set visibility of search bar is false, when user enter one button I am showing the search bar with focus. what my problem is when user click on button I am showing search bar but with that search bar search image also visible. I want to hide that search image. when user started enter text it will hide but I want to hide when search bar is visible.

Comment: Use the other answer to hide is completely : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38200193/4984832

Comment: when I focus search bar when I am showing, that search bar image is showing, If I remove focus it will work fine but I want to focus the search bar.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry I do not understand what you are asking, do you want the search bar icon to display at all?

Comment: Exactly opposite. I want to hide search bar icon at all.

Comment: Thanks Sushi, I am using above link your suggested. It satisfy my requirement. Thank you so much.

Comment: Unbelievable...It's more than 2 years later and the bug is still there...using Resource.Id.search_mag_icon won't work

Answer (score 6):

@SushiHangover's method works fine, but icon appears again once SearchView get focus. 
To fix this, I use LayoutParameters for icon:

```
if(Control!= null){
    ...
    int searchIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier ("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    var icon = (ImageView)searchView.FindViewById (searchIconId);
    icon.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (0, 0);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var plateId = Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
                var plate = Control.FindViewById(plateId);
                plate.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

                SearchView searchView = (base.Control as SearchView);
                var searchIconId = searchView.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_map_icon", null, null);
                var searchIcon = searchView.FindViewById(searchIconId);
                searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);
                searchIcon.RemoveFromParent();

                int textViewId = Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
                EditText textView = (Control.FindViewById(textViewId) as EditText);
                textView.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.ViewStart;
            }
        }
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To customize the icon of the `SearchBar` you need to create a custom renderer where you will customize the `SearchView` android widget:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MySearchBar), typeof(Some.Namespance.MySearchBar_Droid) )]
namespace Some.Namespace
{
    public class MySearchBar_Droid : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged( ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> args )
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(args);    

            SearchView searchView = (base.Control as SearchView);

           //Customize SearchView here
        }
    }
}
```

See [Introduction to Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/) for more details.